# Retrieve mail via PHP / IMAP - Header is changed after fetching the mail

Tags: php, email, header, imap, alias

i have a big Problem. I'll fetch all mails of a mailbox with php_imap, connecting to pop3 service of an microsoft exchange server.

**The Adress of the Mailbox: sample@sample.com**
This Mailbox has many aliases: **e.G. sample_test@sample.com, sample_test2@sample.com**

My problem: When someone writes a mail to sample_test@sample.com the mail is deliverd to the mailbox. So far thats no Problem. When viewing the Header-Source in Microsoft Outlook it displays
To: Sample "sample_test@sample.com"
Still, no problem!

But ...

after receiving this via my php-script and writing the imap_header and imap_body to the file e.G. mail1.eml viewing the source gives me
To: Sample "sample@sample.com"

Here i wish to get
To: Sample "sample_test@sample.com"

My Code:

```
Heres the Snippet for Understanding how i save this to eml file ...

    $mailbox = '{'.$imapHost.':'.$imapPort.'}INBOX';
    $imapStream = imap_open($mailbox, $imapUser, $imapPassword, 0, 1, array('DISABLE_AUTHENTICATOR' => 'GSSAPI'));
    $hdr = imap_check($imapStream);
    $overview = imap_fetch_overview($imapStream, "1:$mailCount");
    $size = count($overview);
    for($i=$count-1;$i>=0;$i--) {

    -->$headers = imap_fetchheader($imapStream, $i, FT_PREFETCHTEXT);
    -->$body = imap_body($imapStream, $i);
    -->file_put_contents($fullPath . '/' . $saveemlfile, $headers . "\n" . $body);

    }
    imap_close($imapStream);
```

Thanks for your Help!

Comment: share the code with us!

Comment: PHP does not modify the headers.  It's just printing out what it got from the IMAP server.  Since you're using Outlook, I assume your backend is Exchange, which can present the message in any format it wants with any headers it wants.